# Checking if two variables are not empty in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to echo variables if either of them aren't empty.

I have written the following PHP but they aren't being shown when the variables aren't empty:

```
if(!empty($this->element->videos||$this->element->productdownloads)) {
    echo $this->element->videos; 
    echo $this->element->productdownloads; 
}
```

Comment: Just chain the conditions? `!empty($this->element->videos) || !empty($this->element->productdownloads)`

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) *"Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error."* You have a *test* inside the function and error reporting (perhaps the error logs) would show you this.

Comment: Do you want to echo both variables? Or just either one?

Comment: The order of precedence says that it does `$this->element->videos || $this->element->productdownloads` first. This evaluates to a boolean value no matter what those variables actually contain. If one of them has some value, this will probably evaluate to true. And doing `!empty()` on a boolean `true` will return `true`. But as Jay Blanchard pointed out, `empty()` only works on variables so you probably have an error.

Comment: (cont.) You probably meant to do `!empty()` on each variable separately. So `if(!empty($this->element->videos) || !empty($this->element->productdownloads))`. But that will try to echo both values even if just one of them has something. So you probably want to use AND `&&` instead of OR `||`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When checking with the OR operator (`||`) the code will execute if one or none of them is empty. But you echo both variables even if one of them is empty.

What I think you want to do is use the AND operator(`&&`). This way, the code will only execute if none of the variables are empty.

```
<?php   if(!empty($this->element->videos) && !empty($this->element->productdownloads)) {
    echo $this->element->videos; 
    echo $this->element->productdownloads; }
?>
```

if you still want to show videos, even if productdownloads is empty (and vice versa), you could do a seperate if for each of them, like this:

```
if(!empty($this->element->videos){
    echo $this->element->videos; 
}
if(!empty($this->element->productdownloads){
    echo $this->element->productdownloads; 
}
```

edit: minor grammatical fixes

Answer (score 6):

```
    <?php   
      if(!empty($this->element->videos) || !empty($this->element->productdownloads)) {
        echo $this->element->videos; 
        echo $this->element->productdownloads; 
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!$this->element->videos || !$this->element->productdownloads) 
{
    echo $this->element->videos; 
    echo $this->element->productdownloads; 
}
```

You dont need to use empty by default php checks for empty when you use ! sign with if condition

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(!($this->element->videos && $this->element->productdownloads)){
    echo $this->element->videos; 
    echo $this->element->productdownloads;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,  I have had quite number of issues like that.

Try to remove empty space from the two variables before comparing them. Sometimes empty spaces comes before the variable and that hinders comparison.